# Why would I care or need to know contact support for yahoo, facebook, and google on contact us page

Tags: discussion

The contact us page bothers me for some reason.  The design of this page just looks odd.  It feels like it was thrown together in a matter of minutes (which it probably was).  Also why would I care about contact / support from the big 3:

Yahoo, Facebook, Google?

[image]

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: "why would I care about contact / support from the big 3:" You don't, but lost cluebies might, and it might stop them from sending a message to SE staff about their FB account.

Comment: Do you know how many times users have posted on Stack Overflow asking about their Facebook account?

Comment: But that is kind of odd Josh.  I mean I am on a support page of Stackoverflow, seeing contact information for Yahoo, Google, etc just doesn't make sense not even for a newbie.

Comment: @Makoto - and this will stop them from that?  I highly doubt this page does anything better but adds more confusion and a more buggy ux.

Comment: Not necessarily *stop* them, but at the bare minimum point them in a better direction to get help should they seek it from that page.

Comment: I'm not talking about programmer newbies, I'm talking about ["my printer just disappeared; what's a mouse"](https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2005/12/12/one-day-in-the-future) people. Not that I entirely disagree with the point you're making...

Comment: @Makoto - I don't agree whatsoever, I can imagine a user (newbie) not understanding and maybe posting a question about as you have mentioned their facebook account but I highly doubt putting contact info to direct you to facebook help is hardly any better.  It complicates things and I just think this is the oddest thing I've ever seen on this site.  I suggest removing this completely I mean honestly that page looks like it is something straight outta the 90s.

Comment: So when does it stop, do we add a help center for linked in?  What about twitter?  How about Quora, lets keep going.  And yahoo may go belly up one day do we manage that.  Come on get rid of this jibberish.

Comment: I'm not sure what it complicates.  "We can't help you with your Facebook account, but Facebook can," is about the nicest thing you can say to someone that posts that question.  I don't necessarily disagree with your *premise*, but I'm of the firm belief that there was a concrete reason to put those links there.

Comment: @Makoto - it looks cheap..it really doesn't help.  If someone is posting jibberish this page in fact doesn't do anything but allows someone from within to link to the contact page to said newbie.

Comment: @Makoto - At what point will that stop - today its facebook, tomorrow twitter and linked in...its just odd that we have that.  If we are going to keep this crap we should at least tuck it away.  We should concentrate on the important contact us...uhh here at stackoverflow and below that should be all this other crud (which should be wiped away anyways).

Comment: Was that recently changed? Because this same question was also raised [13 hours ago](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5091308#5091308) ... The wayback machine doesn't reveal any changes AFAICT: http://web.archive.org/web/20150406140518/http://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: @rene - that was odd am rarely ever in the chat room but I'm glad another smart mind caught this ;-).

Comment: @rene wow the wayback machine has an even uglier one with ubuntu support.  Lord please get rid of all this useless crud.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not linking to the wayback machine to make you instant happy ;)

Comment: @rene - you know me too well :-).

Comment: I hate those buttons and think they're hideous too. But as someone who works in the support desk every day, I'm glad they're there. The moment that new page went live, we saw a very dramatic decline in the number of 3rd-party requests coming through, which is why they stayed. And they will probably stay until we come up with a new contact page, by which I mean **the entire contact page needs to be redone**. It's very outdated and our sites have scaled to the point where it tends to not be very helpful anymore.

Comment: @animuson That 'should be' an answer. But there is no actual question, mmmm...

Answer (score 20):

[Bart's quotation of Oded is correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327959/why-would-i-care-or-need-to-know-contact-support-for-yahoo-facebook-and-google/327962#327962), but it might help you understand if we called it by another name:

It's a [**honeypot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot), a set of links intended to be *irresistibly tempting* to folks who've somehow ended up on our Contact form while desperate to contact... Someone who isn't us.

### Background

Seems there are rather a lot of folks jumping frantically through The Internet looking for some means of contacting Facebook or Google, and since there are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) *about* Facebook and Google, some % of these people end up here.

At which point, they find that "contact us" link we put on every page.

And email us.

As a result, we've been privileged to read some truly heartbreaking stories over the years, of folks trapped in situations you wouldn't wish on your worst enemies. And also a hell of a lot of boring complaints about Google.

But eventually, being a voyeur gets old. You can only be reminded of how terrible humanity is in general, and how terrible social media is in particular so many times before you find your days are consumed searching for remote Montana cabins for sale. In short, it gets in the way of us doing what we're *supposed* to be doing here, which is helping folks who are having problems using Stack Overflow.

So a while back, we got the idea (actually, I believe it was Robert Cartaino & Jon Ericson who came up with this) of creating this "honeypot" for the most common services.

It can be customized per-site to meet the specific needs of that site's audience. For example, [some sites need more bold](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/contact).

Hasn't been a panacea, but I do believe it has helped out a bit.

Comment: Its no wonder none pf this has helped the first sentence points to posting on meta stackoverflow irregardless of any context around it. Notice the important note much below, maybe you did but most others wont. By that time its to late the end user by now has skipped the jibberish and has contacted you. One simple thing you can do to avoid a lot of this. Before they submit their contact us email you force them to check a required check box that states they know they are requesting supportto stackoverflow and support for all other companies google etc will be auto destroyed. Acknowledge it

Comment: Yeah, like the checkbox all new users on Stack Overflow have to check that states they've read the instructions on how to search first and show their work and write detailed specific questions and so on. Wait, no, they just click that and post whatever. Look, we've gone through a fair number of variations here, and will probably go through a lot more... But the key factor seems to be "something eye-catching" not "more text".

Comment: @JonH Your claim that this won't work doesn't hold much weight when compared to [compelling observed evidence](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327964/1159478) that it does in fact work.  Clearly it *does* work.  If you have suggestions for how to make it work *even better*, then sure, propose them, but asserting that the current implementation won't help is clearly not the case.

Comment: Eye catching huh so then make the important note right at the top. There is nothing eye catching about it now.

Comment: You should be surprised...

Comment: As well as add some design aspects to it to make it eye catching. It seems most of the meta questions i ask we end up with some sort of agreement but there is a design or ux lack. Sit with one of the designers and they can make this better.

Comment: Designers don't answer support emails. The last time this page got redesigned, the problem got a lot, lot, *lot* worse afterwards. I think we're mostly interested in what works here, not what looks good.

Comment: Shog that is funny really it is. Design is not just about asthetics but believe it or not they can assist with this process a d lead to less junk email.

Comment: Then why are you complaining about the aesthetics? Form follows function here; it looks like it does today because of a series of changes made to make it work the way we wanted it to. It is a tool worn by the hands of those who use it, not a showpiece.

Comment: You dont tackle it just with programming and crummy links. Ux experts and designers can help with the workflow and leading users to the right area. Clearly this is not communicated well because i see and post a lot of ux issues. Dont believe me?  Just look at my meta posts on job related tags.

Comment: Shog the aesthetics complaint still holds true but that isnt my only complaint.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying that a good UX designer *couldn't* improve this. I'm saying that handing it to a designer and saying "make this good" won't magically fix it; in fact, that's what happened back about 3 years ago, and it wrecked things. It *has* to be an iterative process, and you *can't* put beauty over functionality.

Comment: I agree with that.

Answer (score 14):

[Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) covered this last year on his [blog](http://jericson.github.io/2015/04/08/customer-support-4.html) about building up the support system behind the scenes at Stack Overflow.

In that post he shares a table that shows the problem they were trying to solve:

```
user_type contact.visit     contact.send
--------- -------------  ---------------
Anonymous       337,057  14,007  (4.16%) 
Registered       39,872  20,245 (50.77%)
```

This is showing the types of users that visit the "Contact Us" page and whether or not they actually submit the form. They were trying to reduce the Anonymous contact.send numbers because those are problems that generally related to 3rd party issues:

> Not having an account on our site is the primary calling card of a 3rd party request. Occasionally a user will lose access to their account and sometimes people create accounts thinking it will help them solve their problem with the Apple store or whatnot.

On March 20, 2015 an initial version of the Contact Us page was updated with links to common third parties:

[image: Initial Version]

This showed a reduction in Anonymous users using the form after just 11 days (focus on the percentages)

```
user_type contact.visit     contact.send
--------- -------------  ---------------
Anonymous         8,429     245  (2.91%)
Registered          950     500 (52.63%)
```

Next they tested with the logos to try and get the number even lower.

[image: Version with logos]

After 8 days, this showed even more of an improvement:

```
user_type contact.visit     contact.send
--------- -------------  ---------------
Anonymous         6,702     169  (2.52%)
Registered          603     302 (50.08%)
```

---

The idea behind the links to third parties was to reduce the support time Stack Exchange employees were spending responding to problems they couldn't assist with.

Comment: So, no point in trying to support visitors that can't be bothered to create an account.  News at eleven.

Answer (score 12):

This was discussed in chat [this very day](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5091425#5091425). As [Oded (Stack Overflow developer)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) says there

> what happened was that lots of support emails came in for general FB, Yahoo! and Google were coming in. This is to tell people "this is not the place you are looking for - it is there".

So while not directly useful for most of us, it may prevent employees from having to reply to some general support requests for other websites.

Comment: The only thing this does is brings the point that people are just going to have to then copy paste this link and send it to the same person in that email.  Purely comical...not needed...garbage (how do you say it in french?) -1

Comment: Of all the pages not the contact us page.  The employees could respond with links directly to the help pages for google, etc.  And if you say well its just easier to send them to the contact us page - it really isnt.  If the help center page changes for any of those companies you need to update the contact us page.  Assanine I think is the right word here?

Comment: @JonH if employees find that it really doesn't work, I'm sure they'll address it.

Comment: **sigh** I don't get it...but then again there are a lot of things I don't get.

Comment: Welcome to my world.

Comment: Believe it or not, responding to scores of emails every day with some variation on the boilerplate "Hi! I'm really sorry your mom is dead, but we're not Facebook and can't help you remove her page - you might want to contact them directly" ...gets really old after a few years, @Jon.

Comment: So link them to fb help not contact us

Comment: Hence the big-ass link to fb help *on* contact us. So folks can skip the chore of emailing us just to be told we can't help them, and go somewhere they might actually find help.

Comment: So you think this page stops or prevents that?  Thats not going to help. Your contact us page is ruined. No really its ruined.

Comment: So you use contact us to relink back to fb help?  Atrocious at best from the design / ux side. Please rethink this process. Unless youre looking for hits to this page this solves nothing and ruins the image. Where is @spolsky with his seal of approval?

Comment: No, you're still kinda missing it. [Try my longer explanation below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327959/why-would-i-care-or-need-to-know-contact-support-for-yahoo-facebook-and-google/327963#327963), or maybe consider a scenario where every day the postman delivers your neighbor's mail to you. Eventually, you might tack a note on your mailbox pointing out the location of your neighbor's mailbox, just to save some time.

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful if you used any of those three to login to the site.

Also note that the page for Meta looks exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/contact.

---

They're all options to add as credentials:

> [image: Credentials]

Comment: If you need help logging in with google and facebook you have bigger problems.  We are trying to help the wrong people and the site suffers for that.  If that is the case (the image you posted) a link below the button for the contact page is okay but not the official meta.stackoverflow/contact us page that is just not right.  The contact us page should be about us - stackoverflow - absolutely NO ONE else.  I don't care about the help centers for all these other companies.  If you need help with those companies the contact us page is not the right page for it.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world no one submits the contact form asking about how to install printer drivers. That is just not the world we live in.

As for this contact page (I admit I had not seen the links previously or they did not stand out), I can at least understand the reasoning for those to be there; namely that with a large percentage of users logging in to Stack Overflow using open auth from third party.

If a user is logging in to Stack Overflow using their google account, and lost their google account password, then Stack Overflow cannot help with that. Yet, to that user it may appear as if they simply cannot log in to Stack Overflow.

That said, it would probably be a good idea to at least note that these links are helpful for issues with open auth and not just for general help.

Comment: [It sounds like these *aren't* there for OAuth related users.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327963/1159478).  Apparently there are lots of people that haven't even heard of SO/SE and just end up here when looking for FB/Google/Yahoo support.

Comment: @Servy - Those poor souls. Although, the data is slightly skewed. If I am a registered user, who cannot log in, then I would show up as anonymous if I were trying to retrieve my login credentials.

Comment: Indeed, that's why they don't want/expect that number to go to zero, and why they wouldn't require you to login to submit a request.